# TableRow - Get number of columns

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a dynamic TableRow in android, so I add and delete views from TableRow based on my actions.

I want to check if the table row is full or not, in another word I want to check for example if my table row have 10 views then I move to the second row.

I searched in the documentation, but I can't find a way to get the number of views in a TableRow.

Is there any way to solve this please?

Comment: `TableRow` is a `ViewGroup`, so `getChildCount()` will give you the number of direct children.

Comment: this is really nice, yes I works ;) thank you @MikeM. :)

Comment: In kotlin I do `tableRow1.childCount`

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I didn't notice the [kotlin] tag. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: You can put an answer if you want I will accept it :)

Comment: Oh, I'm good. It was nothing huge. We'll call it a freebie. :-) I could probably find a duplicate, or you could post an answer yourself, or just delete this, if you like. Whichever you prefer. Thank you, though. I do appreciate the offer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m):

> `TableRow` is a `ViewGroup`, so `getChildCount()` will give you the number
>   of direct children

The solution with kotlin is:

```
if (tableRow1.childCount < 10)
   // action
```